# How to use NTSC Xbox in Europe

Tags: xbox

I just bought myself an original Xbox (NTSC) and I currently live in Europe (Germany). I have a question regarding NTSC/PAL:
What can I do about the voltage difference of the sockets in germany (230V) and the voltage the console needs (110V). I am pretty sure if I just plug it in my console it will get fried. And as far as I know the socket also puts out 50Hz and the Xbox needs 60Hz (like the socket output in the US) if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Could you take a couple pictures from the cable and the place on the Xbox where you would normally plug it in (without anything else plugged in)? That could help me in determining possible options.

Comment: What are the output video options on the Xbox, and what are your input options (hardware connectors) for your intended display?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know the voltages accepted by you Xbox unit, just look at the sticker right next to the power port. It will list the required amps as well as frequency.

The voltages should also be listed in the Xbox manual.

Comment: I checked that, it's what I wrote above. My question is what I do about the difference... I think I can buy a converter to turn down the volts, not sure about the frequenzy doe

Answer (score 1):

NTSC and PAL are analogue TV standards and you don't have to worry here - all modern TVs (actually even most of the old CRT ones) have no problem between understanding those two.

When it comes to the power - well from what I've [read](https://www.reddit.com/r/xboxone/comments/4kki0f/us_xbox_one_on_europe/) it seems that XBox power supply is not as universal as for example PS4 one - while the latter one would accept 100-240V, the former is either built only for 110 V or 230 V. Read PRECISELY what is written on the power supply.

If you can, just buy an European power brick for your XBox.